# What considerations to be made to change a static Member to a non static member

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm debugging an ASP.NET C# application where some programmer defined a member of a class as public static string.

```
namespace redacted.products
{
    public partial class details : BasePage
    {
        public static string fileName;
    }
 }
```

The class *details* extends *BasePage* which in turn extends *System.Web.UI.Page* object.

I've identified this as the cause of a bug.  In a nutshell, the fileName that is stored in that member is available to every session that visits our site until changed by a visitors action or the application pool is reset.

I'd like to convert the member to a non static version instead so that the value doesn't persist.

What considerations do I need to make before doing this?

I've used Visual Studio's Find all  references feature and there are no instances of this member being accessed as *details*.fileName.

I've also searched for *details*.fileName and confirmed nothing else extends the *details* class.

Comment: "there are no instances of this member being accessed as details.fileName." - then this field is not the cause of any bugs, as it's unused.

Comment: If you're _certain_ that you don't want it to be the same across the entire project, you can change it. The only difference is that each session will need to have its own instance of `details` somewhere. Figuring out where to put each of those instances will be tricky.

Comment: @dai it is referenced as fileName within the Page_load method instead of details.fileName

Comment: @serverSentinel that's purely syntactical. Use "Find all References" instead of a text-based search.

Comment: :-/  ... "I've used Visual Studio's Find all references feature"